# How to limit django-allauth to only give access to pre-defined social accounts

Tags: django, django-allauth

I have a B2B app written in Django.
Currently all users are registered manually (no real signup page).

Now I want to implement django-allauth to be able to authenticate users thru MS ADs or Google. The only limitation is, that I want to pre-define the users that can use this authentication.

Is there any possibility to define these users in allauth?